# web2py dropbox integration

Tags: python, dropbox, web2py, dropbox-api

I am having a difficulty using a dropbox session in web2py. Here is my default controller with 2 methods:

```
def index():
    APP_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
    APP_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
    ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'
    sess = dropbox.session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
    request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()
    url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token, "http://localhost:8000/dropbox/default/welcome")
    redirect(url)

def welcome():
    ## How do I get the session object here??
    access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
    client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(sess)
    return dict(message=T("Welcome user!" + client.account_info()))
```

I have tried using current.session, and also tried to cache the session but it didn't work for me.

Can someone provide some help on how to save the dropbox session in the index method and be able to use it in other methods/controllers. Code samples would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put something like this(untested) in models, so dropbox_session will become available for all controllers ...

```
def __make_dropbox_connection():
    sess = dropbox.session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)

    print("DROPBOX Connection established ...")
    return sess

##
dropbox_sess = cache.ram('dropbox',__make_dropbox_connection,None)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to figure another way save the request token and dropbox session without using the cache. My second question is what's the difference between web2py session and current.session. Are the variables that you store in current.session persistent?